# What function does python -m unittest execute?

Tags: python, python-unittest

In python 2.6, I've been reading through the [unittest documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/unittest.html). But I still haven't found this answer.

What function does pyton -m unittest execute?

For example, how would I modify this code such that just executing `python -m unittest` would detect it and run the test?

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, random.sample, self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

EDIT:
Note this is just a example, I'm actually trying to get it to detect and run multiple tests as a suite, here is my starting point - but `python -m  unittest` doesn't detect it nor does `python -m unittest discovery` work with it. I have to call `python discovery.py` to execute it.

discovery.py:

```
import os
import unittest


def makeSuite():
    """Function stores all the modules to be tested"""
    modules_to_test = []
    test_dir = os.listdir('.')
    for test in test_dir:
        if test.startswith('test') and test.endswith('.py'):
            modules_to_test.append(test.rstrip('.py'))

    all_tests = unittest.TestSuite()
    for module in map(__import__, modules_to_test):
        module.testvars = ["variables you want to pass through"]
        all_tests.addTest(unittest.findTestCases(module))
    return all_tests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(defaultTest='makeSuite')
```

Comment: `python -m unittest your_test_module_name`.

Comment: @falsetru yes that would work, but I don't want to actually specify each test... `python -m unittest -h` seems to imply there is a "default"... so what is that default...

Comment: If you use Python 2.7+, you can use `python -m unittest discover`. But that's introduced in Python 2.7.   How about using `py.test` / `nose` ?

Comment: I'd have to get `py.test` or `nose` pushed through security. If I don't have to do that... I'd be happier :-) Maybe I could write my own "discover" I think I'm half way there, but calling `python -m unittest Suite` or `Suite.makeSuite` fails for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

`python -m something` executes the module `something` as a script.  i.e. from `python --help`:

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

The unittest module [can be run as a script](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b15c5a66213f/Lib/unittest/__main__.py) -- And the arguments that you pass to it determine which files it tests.  The commandline interface is also documented in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface).

Comment: Ah I see that `-m unittest` is documented in 2.7 (I'm stuck with 2.6). Seems that I'm stuck writing my own discovery widget... Now I just need to get my current code to work for `-m unittest`...